# Windows Service Installer C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am working on a task, where I need to create a installer (.msi/exe) which can install my application as an Windows Service. Also, I need to deploy this service from a non-alterable medium (i.e from CDROM). But I have my configuration files in the CDROM which I want to copy them to a local folder on hard drive before hosting the service. I understand there are different ways for creating a installer 
1) Using Install shield wizard in Visual Studio
2) Advanced Installers

Which option do you think is optimal for my problem? Also, I am not sure if it is possible to copy configuration files to Hard Drive and leave the dll's on the disk while installation.

Please guide me through the right direction.

Comment: Any thoughts on my question

Comment: "leave the dll's on the disk" - why is this an important part of the problem space? Why not do what most installers do and put everything onto the hard drive? Do you really want the service to break if someone needs to put a different CD in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally clear what your real problem is, however, I try an answer:

> > But I have my configuration files in the CDROM which I want to copy them to a local folder on hard drive before hosting the service

If these files can be integrated in the VS solution, they can be tagged as "Content" (Build Action) and copied to the install location during setup. If you need to be more flexible, you can write a setup extension.

> > and leave the dll's on the disk while installation

I do not understand this. Which DLLs ?

If you are interested in some tips for creating a sample service with a complete setup, you can check my SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28853490/4547223

Or look at: http://www.rsprog.de/samplewindowsservice/

You may probably comment you experiences with that and tell us which files do you want to copy to which location and more about the background. I will try to refine my answer then.

Comment: I have few dll's which my service code is dependent upon. I dont want those dll's to be copied over to the HardDrive only the configuration files need to get copied to Hard drive. I am just thinking if I need to write my custom application which can do this or is there any other tool which can give me this control.

Comment: So it seems you don't need a setup tool, just a program to copy your config files. I would go with a custom app or some powershell scripts...

Comment: Yes apparently, I cannot use any setup wizards as they make a copy of the files in the hardDrive...So I am going by an 2 setup tools approach..the first one will host my application as a windows service and second one will save the configurations to system registry. After which the service is started, which reads data from registry and runs its functionality..thank you all for ur comments...